# Enabling an Active Directory account using JNDI

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I have successfully created a disabled user in Active Directory via JNDI, but I am not sure how to enable it.  Am I supposed to manipulate the userAccountControl attribute directly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

Here are some values and [the explanation how to use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245673%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) :

```
UF_TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT       0x0100
UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT               0x0200
UF_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT     0x0800
UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT     0x1000
UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT       0x2000
UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD           0x10000
UF_SCRIPT                       0x0001
UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE               0x0002
UF_HOMEDIR_REQUIRED           0x0008
UF_LOCKOUT                     0x0010
UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD               0x0020
UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE           0x0040
```

[Exhaustive list of values here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245514%28v=prot.10%29.aspx).

For example

```
userAccountControl = 544
```

544 = 0x220 = UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD