# Enabling/Disabling Active Directory User with JNDI

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm having trouble finding information on how to enable or disable a user in Active Directory using JNDI.  Here's the LDAP context creator and enable/disable user methods I've put together so far ...

```
private static final String USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE = "userAccountControl";
private static final int UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x2;

public static LdapContext getLdapContext(String host, int port, String username, String password) throws NamingException {

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + host + ":" + port);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "false");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "60000"); // Wait up to 1 minute for pooled connection before timing out
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "tokenGroups");
    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSID");

    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    return ctx;
}

public static void enableUser(LdapContext ctx, String dn) throws NamingException {
    int userAccountControlOrig = (int) ctx.getAttributes(dn).get(USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE).get();
    int userAccountControlValue = userAccountControlOrig & ~UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE,""+userAccountControlValue));
    ctx.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
}

public static void disableUser(LdapContext ctx, String dn) throws NamingException {
    int userAccountControlOrig = (int) ctx.getAttributes(dn).get(USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE).get();
    int userAccountControlValue = userAccountControlOrig | UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE,""+userAccountControlValue));
    ctx.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
}
```

But I am not sure if my logic of computing the new value for the `userAccountControl` attribute is correct.  I figured the right way to derive this would be by getting it from the LDAP Context object, casting it to an `int`, and then logically ORing it with the `UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` UF_FLAG code (in the case of disable) or logically ANDing it with the inverse of the `UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` UF_FLAG (in the case of enable).  Are there anything corrections needed in my logic, or any suggestions for a better way to go about accomplishing this?  The other post on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623733/enabling-an-active-directory-account-using-jndi) did not divulge any coding logic specifics, unfortunately.

Comment: Your code and logic look good to me. Do you have an actual problem, or do you just want to verify your approach before breaking something?

Comment: Oh: `new BasicAttribute(USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE,""+userAccountControlValue)` - Are you sure you want to set the attribute to a string value? I'd first try a numerical parameter.

Comment: @HannoBinder Thank you!  I don't have an actual problem, but I don't have an instance of Active Directory available to me to test against before I submit this for System Testing, so I wanted to be sure I had everything correct to be certain as possible my code won't mess up anything in the Active Directory instance in my project's test lab.

Comment: @HannoBinder Well the examples I've seen of altering the `userAccountControl` attribute all set it to a string like I did above. I didn't find anything else to the contrary so I just left it that way, but have you seen any examples where it's just set to an `int`?

Comment: I can't seem to find an example where a string is not used, so `String` is probably the right type to use. - You may want to relocate your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Maybe there's someone there who can give a more qualified answer than me.